# How to add custom build/deploy commands on OpenShift

Tags: python, flask, openshift, gunicorn

I'm trying to properly build and deploy a Flask application to OpenShift.

The application uses `SQLAlchemy` as an ORM, and `Flask-Migrate` to do the database migrations.

My app resides in `autoapp.py` with the following content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Create an application instance."""
from tcst_api.app import create_app
from tcst_api.utils import get_config_object

CONFIG = get_config_object()
application = create_app(CONFIG)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

To initialize the app and start it, I do the following locally:

```
export FLASK_APP=autoapp.py

flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade

flask run
```

On the OpenShift side, I managed to set up the `FLASK_APP` environment variable, and the platform also can hook the source and is able to build it.

However I don't know where can I inject the `flask db ...` commands into the process.

I use `gunicorn` to serve the app, and OpenShift manages to find.

Comment: Suggest you read https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ it talks about introducing custom steps into build and run phases for your image, as well as deployment lifecycle. For example, to safely do a migrate it needs to be done from a mid lifecycle hook, where you are using ``Recreate`` deployment strategy.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Can you link me to that section please?

Comment: It is covered across a couple of chapters at least. Lifecycle hooks are covered in chapter on application lifecycle management. For doing stuff in the container, need to look at chapter Customising Source-to-Image Builds, but you really need to read chapters before to properly understand.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I've read the book, and changed to deployment strategy to `Recreate`, also added a `mid` lifecycle hook to the `recreateParams` with the following command `/bin/sh -c flask db init && flask db migrate && flask db upgrade`, however the deployment gets stuck and fails. Can I PM you somehow to get some more intel on the topic?

Comment: Use the OpenShift group if want to have a better discussion about it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openshift

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Now it the hook executes the commands without any modifications, maybe it was a company cluster issue, not sure. However the changes won't persist in the final pod, which would be my original concern. How can I execute commands during deployment which output will persist in the deployed pod?

Comment: You would have to have a separate database such as PostgreSQL. Are you trying to run this with SQLite in local file system of the container?

Comment: At the moment I do, but obviously these containers are not appropriate for that. Now I tried to create a persistent storage, to store the db file and the migrations there, but it seems like our cluster doesn't support persistent volumes. Moving to PostgreSQL could be an option yes, but still I need to store my migrations somewhere persistent, how should I do that?

Comment: As I understand things with Django, don't know about Flask, you would generate your database migrations as part of the S2I build, or they would even be part of the original source code repo, so they end up being part of the image. The generation of them doesn't require the database to be present as far as I know. Only the actual database upgrade would need to be done during deployment.

Comment: The Flask db migrate command even suggests that you need to review the result before using. So definitely looks like you should be doing this on your own system and checking result into the repo which then goes into the build.